# What's the default state of the 'include preview in document by default' option in KeyNote?

Tags: keynote, iwork

I'm a Linux user, and trying to figure out if Apple Keynote documents include a PDF preview by default. I don't have easy access to a Mac with iWork, so I can't really tell by myself.

Comment: The default state is off. Your question is off too. Offtopic. http://apple.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

I just checked and it's not checked by default in my Keynote when I try to save a file. Hope that helps :)

Comment: Thanks! This is a lot of help.

Comment: Would you mind flagging this as the accepted answer if this helped you out. Thanks.